# Why other unrelated processes are killed when one process is killed in docker container

Tags: docker, process

processes before process 48 is killed:

[image: processes before process 48 is killed]

I then killed process 48, and found process 61 (irrelated with process 48 I think) and its descendants are all killed :

[image: processes after process 48 is killed]

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

When you kill the foreground process running in a container, the container stops which takes any other processes with it.

The `STIME` for each process has updated including PID 1, somehow your container has restarted after the process was killed. Are you using the `--restart always` option?